# Rubymine(mac)'s embedded Terminal cannot handle Chinese characters correctly

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, terminal, rubymine

I'm using Rubymine 7.1, when I type Chinese characters in the embedded Terminal, it shows me only half of the character, is there anyone else who met this problem before?

The snapshot is [here](https://p6.zdusercontent.com/attachment/218696/dpr1OvfOJSZ4t1ZM3Zl7rHYeb?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..3jeBe9Bmw84gopR0k8tuhA.dtNwLWQNHv5dGT0OBOG5UPuU98DfESMAOCjDbl5FEB3A7R2IWyYYwmO8nWbRACj5ws6opCvF-4YP6yk0CrYbRRFdS62aKoob7Y4MoihcrNyac8avXWjy1U91odiWsCaFUYrFBwEMPiU7hRhQTpTtVMyhBtH6hAGLhzQTkWHqD5A5Arda7q2WxAX06AhJHnUN12DUJdn3twGuixTx6Tck0g.M8hMC7QGHQXZWIqROvCBmQ)

Answer (score 0):

Handling double-width characters properly is a locale issue.  Since the characters come *out* without losing information, it looks more like a problem in the output-settings.  JetBrains' documentation mentions this, e.g., [RubyMine 7.1.3 Help/Configuring Output Encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-output-encoding.html)

```
`-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, after I tried your idea, but it still works bad.